# barajas con python

Tags: python, poo, random

Estoy intentando crear un juego que cree una baraja normal y después te baraje esa baraja para que tengan sitios ramdom, es un ejercicio que se debe hacer con clases.

He intentado de todo pero no se me ocurre la manera de crear la baraja en si, como una clase que contenga en este caso 40 subclases, cada una una carta con sus propios atributos de palo y numero.

```
    import random
class carta:
   def __init__(self):
    self.escojer_palo = random.randint(1,4)
    self.palo  = "ninguno"
    if int(self.escojer_palo) == 1:
        self.palo = "copas"
    if int(self.escojer_palo) == 2:
        self.palo = "bastos"
    if int(self.escojer_palo) == 3:
        self.palo = "oros"
    if int(self.escojer_palo) == 4:
        self.palo = "espadas"
    print(self.palo)
    

   
           
           
           

for i in range(0,3):
    carta1 = carta()
```

esto es lo único que tengo, por favor ayúdenme

Comment: Las cartas no deberías generarlas aleatoriamente, sino ordenarlas aleatoriamente. Puedes crear una clase `Carta` que simplemente tenga los atributos `palo` y `numero` y luego una clase `Baraja` que instancie cada carta para generar todas las de la baraja, almacenarlas en alguna estructura como una lista en un atributo de instancia  y luego agregarle un método `barajar` para distribuirlas "aleatoriamente".

Comment: Usar if es muy engorroso, mejor usa un array: palo=["Ninguno","copas","bastos","oros","espadas"]; y después para obtener la carta: carta=palo[int(self.escojer_palo)];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identificamos dos clases: **Carta** y **Baraja**, donde la primera define una carta en particular, y la segunda es una colección de cartas.

Primero creamos una clase enumerada para usar nombres en lugar de valores para identificar los palos:

```
from enum import Enum

class Palo(Enum):
    COPAS = 1,
    BASTOS = 2,
    ESPADAS = 3,
    OROS = 4
```

Por lo que podemos decir Palo.COPAS en lugar de usar el valor 1 directamente. Es más legible y mejor documentado.

Definamos la Carta:

```
class Carta:
    def __init__(self, palo: Palo, valor: int):
        self.palo = palo
        self.valor = valor

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.palo} {self.valor}"
```

En ella guardamos el palo y valor. Lo único adicional es definir el método mágico `__str__`, que devuelve la representación textual de la carta.

Ahora la baraja:

```
class Baraja:
    def __init__(self, cartas_palo=10):
        self.cartas = []
        for palo in Palo:
            for valor in range(cartas_palo):
                self.cartas.append(Carta(palo, valor + 1))

    def barajar(self):
        self.cartas = sample(self.cartas, len(self.cartas))

    def extraer(self) -> Carta:
        return self.cartas.pop() if self.cartas else None
```

Como hay barajas de distintos tamaños, la clase recibe como parámetro el número de cartas por palo, y con eso crea automáticamente todas las cartas involucradas, usando valores desde 1 en adelante.

La clase tiene un método para barajar (desordenar) la baraja. La forma más rapida de desordenar una lista es usar el método `sample` del módulo `random`.

Finalmente, el método `extraer()` te devuelve una carta de la baraja, eliminandola. Cuando ya no quedan cartas, devuelve `None`. Siempre vamos a extraer la última carta de la lista.

**Demo**

Crea una baraja, la desordena y luego reparte todas las cartas:

```
from enum import Enum
from random import sample

class Palo(Enum):
    COPAS = 1,
    BASTOS = 2,
    ESPADAS = 3,
    OROS = 4

class Carta:
    def __init__(self, palo: Palo, valor: int):
        self.palo = palo
        self.valor = valor

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.palo} {self.valor}"

class Baraja:
    def __init__(self, cartas_palo=10):
        self.cartas = []
        for palo in Palo:
            for valor in range(cartas_palo):
                self.cartas.append(Carta(palo, valor + 1))

    def barajar(self):
        self.cartas = sample(self.cartas, len(self.cartas))

    def extraer(self) -> Carta:
        return self.cartas.pop() if self.cartas else None


baraja = Baraja(10)
baraja.barajar()
while True:
    carta = baraja.extraer()
    if carta:
        print(carta)
    else:
        break
```

produce:

```
Palo.BASTOS 7
Palo.ESPADAS 5
Palo.BASTOS 2
Palo.OROS 3
Palo.OROS 6
Palo.COPAS 6
Palo.COPAS 2
... etc ...
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, en el método extraer puedes mejorarlo con: return self.cartas.pop() if self.cartas else None; #Asi resumes un poco el código con la misma funcionalidad.

Comment: Sugerencia aceptada, @DABL03